# Sin taylor series recursive approximation

Tags: java, recursion, trigonometry, taylor-series

I need some insight on my recursive method of calculating the sin Taylor series, which doesn't work properly. The method calls two other recursive methods which are a recursive pow method and a recursive factorial method. I compared my findings with an iterative sin method giving me the correct solution. What is missing in my recursive sin method ?

> Approximation of sin(x)= x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! -x^7/7!+ ...

```
public class SinApprox
    {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            Out.println(sinx(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1));
            Out.print(sinIT(2));
        }

    static double sinIT(double x)
    {
        double sin = 0;
        double a = x;
        double b = 1;
        double term = a/b;
        double vz = 1;
        double i = 1;

    while(term > 0.000001)
    {
        i = i +2;
        sin = sin + (term*vz);
        a= rekursivPow(x,i);
        b = rekursivN(i);
        term = a/b;
        vz = -1 * vz;
    }
    return sin;
}

static double rekursivN(double n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * rekursivN(n-1);
}

static double rekursivPow(double x , double y)
{
    if(y  == 1)
    {
        return x ;
    }
    return x * rekursivPow(x , y  - 1);
}

static double sinx(double i ,double n, double x, double y, double vz, double sum, double pow)
{


    double term = pow / n;

    if(term > 0.000001)
    {
        sum = sum + (term * vz);
        vz = -1 * vz;
        i = i +2;
        n = rekursivN(i);
        y = y +2;
        pow = rekursivPow(x ,y);

        return sinx(i, n, x , y , vz, sum, pow);
    }
    return sum;


   }
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing this with recursion for a homework exercise? Because if you had to actually implement this "for real", there is literally zero reason to do this with recursive calls.

Comment: Yes it's homework and I need to use for my recursive sin method the pow and factorial recursive methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one would be to write out the function in a way that makes the recursive relationship clear (you can't write code for what isn't clear) so, don't start with this:

```
sin(x)= x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! -x^7/7!+ ...
```

But instead, ask "how can I make all those terms with `x` look the same":

```
sin(x)= x^1/1! - x^3/3! + x^5/5! + ...
```

Good start, but if we're recursing, what we're really looking for is something that *only* computes one of those terms, and then calls itself with updated arguments to compute the next term. Ideally, we want something like:

```
doThing(args) {
  return simpleComputation() + doThings(updatedargs);
}
```

And then recursion does the rest. So let's first make sure that we only ever have to deal with `+` instead of a mix of `+` and `-`:

```
sin(x)= (-1)^0 * x^1/1! + (-1)^1 * x^3/3! + (-1)^2 * x^5/5! + ...
```

And now you have something you can actually express as a recursive relation, because:

```
sin(x,n) {
  return (-1)^n * x^(2n+1) / (2n+1)! + sin(x, n+1);
}
```

With the "shortcut" function:

```
sin(x) {
  return sin(x,0); 
}
```

And that's where the hints stop, you should be able to implement the rest yourself. As long as you remember to *stop* the recursion because a Taylor series is infinite, and computer programs and resources are not.

Comment: But isn't this (-1)^0 * x^1/1! supposed to be positive ? -1^0 is -1.

Comment: It _most certainly_ is not. `-1 ^ 0` is definitely +1 (with several explanations, all of which are easily found on the web)

Comment: My mistake , sorry

Comment: Thank you it worked =) But I do have another question. My recursivePow method only works with positive digits. Do you have any hints how I can achieve it with real numbers like for example : -0.12^2 ?